# Unable to remove titlebar in android

Tags: android, titlebar

I have tried all of these 3 methods but still can't remove the titlebar.

This method removes the titlebar in the androidstudio(1.4) but i can still see the titlebar in the emulator:[image]

And this two methods crashes the app:[image]

[image]

Styles.xml:
[image]

EDIT(How to fix): It will work if you Inheriting from the activity instead of appcompat in the java file.

Comment: post your all styles.xml file screenshot here

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace of your crashes? If you’re using AppCompat then your application theme must inherit from the AppCompat theme.

Comment: Love you bro! It's working if i inherit from activity instead of appcompat.Thanks curtisLoew

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

post this lines in all styles.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **styles.xml** to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and in manifest:

change your activity theme to:

```
<activity
android:theme="@styles/AppTheme
....
```

Comment: can you post your logcat here

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom theme;

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

And apply it in your manifest

```
 <application
    android:theme="@styles/CustomTheme"
```

Or use it directly as:

```
 <application
    android:theme="Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

try placing this in your styles.xml

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

and apply the theme to your application

Comment: <application  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >